# Count Facebook post sharing with progress bar

Tags: facebook, count, progress-bar, share

I would like to make a bar displaying how many times a post was shared. 
I'm a complete newbie about Facebook Debug so I would like to know if it's possible to do it and if I can animate this through JQuery.

Any comment or proposal is appreciated.

Comment: How would a progress bar makes sense to display an arbitrary number? A progress bar requires that you have a target value.

Comment: Hello, the bar is not so important, I would like to know more how to display the number of shares :)

Comment: The `post` object has a field `shares`, that holds the info you want. But how to make an API request etc. is way to broad to explain here; so if you don’t know how that works, please go read up on it first.

Comment: It's quite true. Thanks